# Universal cover of $SO^+(p,q)$

Tags: lie-groups

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) page of $SO^+(p,q)$, they do not mention any details about its universal cover. Google searches also did not give any relevant results.

So, what is the universal cover of $SO^+(p,q)$, and how do we prove that it is indeed the universal cover?

Comment: It's difficult to describe it concretely in general. For low $p$ and $q$, there are some "accidental" descriptions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Indefinite_signature).

Comment: Note that $Spin(p,q)$ is a double cover of $SO^+(p,q)$, and thus not the universal cover for $p,q>1$. In the case that $Spin(p,q)$ is the universal cover, it can be explicitly constructed via Clifford algebras.

Comment: @Kajelad Why is $Spin(p,q)$ not the universal cover for $p,q > 1$?

Comment: @IshanDeo $Spin(p,q)$ is a double cover of $SO^+(p,q)$, whereas the universal covering is a $|\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))|$-fold covering, where $|\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))|$ is the cardinality of the fundamental group, which is generally greater than 2 (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group#Topology)).