# Double cover vs universal cover for ${\rm SO}^+(p,q)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, covering-spaces

I am confused about the double covers and universal cover of ${\rm SO}^+(p,q)$, where by this notation I mean the connected component with the identity. Previously I thought that ${\rm SO}^+(p,q)$ had the property that it is doubly connected and that the universal cover matches the double cover. But in [comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272083/universal-cover-of-sop-q) it is said that this is not true: if $p>1,q>1$ the double cover does not match the universal cover. However, in this [Phys.SE thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/780700/why-the-double-covering) it is claimed, as I've seem many times being done in Physics, that for ${\rm SO}^+(p,q)$ groups the universal cover is the double cover.

Someone is clearly wrong because the statements are in contradiction. What is really the case? Is the universal cover of ${\rm SO}^+(p,q)$ the same as the double cover or not if $p>1,q>1$? And more importantly, how can we prove this?

Comment: Do not believe math statements that you find in the physics literature, unless you know a reference in math literature. Incidentally, $SO(p,q)$ is not even connected if $pq\ne 0$.

Comment: I think this is a very wise advice. Can you give me a reference in math that discusses this matter in detail? On the issue with connectedness, I believe it was a bad notation I used. I actually was talking about the connected component with the identity. I changed the notation to ${\rm SO}^+(p,q)$.

Comment: The maximal compact connected subgroup in $SO(p,q)$ is $SO(p)\times SO(q)$.

Comment: I will have to look for a reference when I have more time.

Comment: @Gold, you are certainly correct that $\pi_1$ of a _connected_ real Lie group is the "covering group" of its universal cover... That's a general fact... :)

Comment: Since $SO^+(p,q)$ is homotopy-equivalent to its maximal compact subgroup, the fundamental group is the product $\pi_1(SO(p))\times \pi_1(SO(q))$. If both $p,q>2$, this group is the product of two groups of order 2, hence has order 4. If $p$ or $q$ equals 2, then the fundamental group is infinite. Hence, the physics claim is **always** false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some generalities from algebraic topology (you can find these in any algebraic topology textbook). Suppose that $M$ is, say, a connected manifold (this works for a much larger class of topological spaces but we will not need this). Then the covering spaces of $M$ are classified (up to an isomorphism) by subgroups of the fundamental group of $M$. Furthermore, the degree of a covering map $M_H\to M$ corresponding to a subgroup $H\le \pi_1(M)$ equals the index of $H$ in $\pi_1(M)$. In particular, if $H$ is the trivial subgroup, $M_H\to M$ is the universal covering map and its degree equals the order (aka the cardinality) of $\pi_1(M)$. Thus, you are effectively asking about the order of the fundamental group $\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))$, where $p>1, q>1$.

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $K< G$ be its maximal compact subgroup. It is a general fact $G$ is diffeomorphic to the product of $K$ and some Euclidean space (see the references given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup)). (All maximal compact subgroups are conjugate to each other, hence, it does not matter which one you take.) In particular, $\pi_1(G)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(K)$. Thus, in order to compute $\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))$ we need to  identify the/a maximal compact subgroup  of $SO^+(p,q)$. You can find this, for instance, in

*Helgason, Sigurdur*, [**Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces.**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/384537), Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 34. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xxvi, 641 p. (2001). [ZBL0993.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0993.53002).

A free (and better, in my opinion) reference is Brian Konrad's online notes "[Examples of maximal compact subgroups](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/210CPage/handouts/maxcompact.pdf)".

In any case, the maximal compact subgroup of $O(p,q)$ is $O(p)\times O(q)$, which yields $SO(p)\times SO(q)$ for $SO^+(p,q)$. Thus,
$$
\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))\cong \pi_1(SO(p))\times \pi_1(SO(q)). 
$$

You can find a computation of $\pi_1(SO(n)), n\ge 2$ in many places, for instance, in the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123650/fundamental-group-of-the-special-orthogonal-group-son)  question. But you probably already know that $\pi_1(SO(2))\cong {\mathbb Z}$ and $\pi_1(SO(n))\cong {\mathbb Z}_2$, $n\ge 3$.

Thus, we obtain:

(a) If $p=q=2$, then $\pi_1(SO(p))\times \pi_1(SO(q))\cong {\mathbb Z}^2$ (hence, is infinite).

(b) If $p>2, q=2$, then $\pi_1(SO(p))\times \pi_1(SO(q))\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times {\mathbb Z}$ (hence, is infinite).

(c) if $p>2, q>2$, then $\pi_1(SO(p))\times \pi_1(SO(q))\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times {\mathbb Z}_2$ has order four.

In particular, in all cases, $\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))$ has order 4 or is infinite; it **never** has order two as long as $p>1, q>1$.

The bottom line is that for $p>1, q>1$ the universal cover of $SO^+(p,q)$ is **never** the (2-fold) spin-cover $Spin(p,q)$. I am not sure about the origin of the claim in the physics literature that $Spin(p,q)$ is the universal cover of $SO^+(p,q)$. Most likely, somebody have read that the universal cover of $SO^+(n,1), n\ge 3$, is $Spin(n,1)$ (which is true, of course) and extrapolated (without thinking) to all indefinite orthogonal groups.